# Loading AngularJS based on browser version throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an angularJS application that we need to support on IE8 as well as modern browsers.

Since AngularJS 1.3+ does not support IE8, I want to test  if the browser is IE8 and if so load angularJS 1.2.27 else 1.3.14

This is what I tried:

```
    <script>


$(function () {

    if (isIE8()) {
    $.getScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        $.getScript("wte_allocationapproval.js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

        });
    });
    } else {
    $.getScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {       
        $.getScript("wte_allocationapproval.js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        });
    });
    }


});
</script>
    <!---<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="wte_allocationapproval.js"></script> --->
    <div ng-app="AllocationApprovalApp">
        <div ng-controller="AllocationApprovalController">
```

wte_allocationapproval.js has all the NG code. Everything works just fine if I use simple script tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="wte_allocationapproval.js"></script>
```

But when I try to do the dynamic loading I get:

[image]

**NOTES:**

1. I have to support IE8. I cannot ask my clients to upgrade their browsers.
2. Please don't diverge from the point of the post by trying advise on how to identify browser versions.

Comment: Why not use conditional comments?

Comment: Why don't you just have a conditional html comment and from that, display an 'upgrade your browser' message?

Comment: @TonyBarnes come on guys, answer the question, not change it. My clients cannot upgrade browsers and how I identify the browser is not relevant to this question,

Comment: We're not changing the question - we're suggesting a better approach.

Comment: There's no need to be rude Sajjan. What you are trying to do is a bad practice. Hence why everyone has told you to use conditional comments instead of trying to use different versions of angular for different browser versions.

Comment: @TonyBarnes Sorry, I dont want to be rude. How does using conditional comments save me from using different versions of angularJS?

Comment: Why not just use Angular 1.2 for all browsers?  Is it that 1.3 supports some newer browser that 1.2 doesn't?  Or 1.3 has a feature missing in 1.2?  I'm curious, we're staying with 1.2 for now because we also support IE8.

Comment: If you have to build for IE8, why are you using a version that doesn't support it? If you conditionally switch you risk breaking a lot... It's something you should figure out in the scope before you build and decide upon then? If your client says they have to use ie8, then use libraries that support ie8, no?

Comment: @NicholasSmith No reason other than to be able to use the latest when I can. But Im also curious to know why method is not working (bad as it may be) and open to ways in which I dont have to load different versions.

Comment: @ajmajmajma OK, maybe i am risking. But can someone actually answer the question!!!

Comment: There is no real great answer, because it is general practice that you would decide upon with the client before you build what you will be supporting in the app. It is not at all uncommon to say if a client wants cutting edge, you require they use cutting edge (browsers), or at least evergreen browsers. You could use juste HTML conditionals - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , but its really not good practice.

Comment: These are things you decide upon before building. You aren't getting answers because this is something you should never do. You swap code you built in 1.3 to now run in 1.2, you will have to change the code so it runs in both (if that is even possible). You should to go to your client and discuss this before you open potential huge problems

Comment: A good answer would be to use 1.3 in IE8, here you go: https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to server side templating such as Java (JSP), .NET, PHP etc, you could look at the incoming user agent and serve back the version you want based on that.  I'm not sure how problematic that would be.  In Java, it would look something like:

```
<%  String ua = request.getHeader(“User-Agent”);
    boolean IE8 = (ua != null && ua.indexOf(“MSIE 8″) != -1);  %>
<% if(IE8) { %>
   <script src="angular12">
<% } else { %>
   <script src="angular13">
<% } %>
```